# why are there two ways of action handling in form in php?

Tags: php

[form handling in php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlrM9.png)

1st snippet :

```
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
         Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
         Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
         <input type = "submit" />
      </form>
```

2nd snippet :

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php 
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

how does 2nd snippet in action handling in php work?

Comment: I have no problem understanding 1st one.

Comment: You should put `echo` in your first code.

Comment: htmlspecualchars used to prevent from xss attack for more  [click here]
  (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is. First snipped looks wrong to me, but that depends on the code before that line. Have you just tested both to understand where the differences are (if there are any).

Comment: Thanks Mayur. Thanks Markus. I will have a look at it.